# Undefined method for nil:NilClass while calling controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need some advice on this problem. Inside my View I am calling one method like this:

```
<%= image_tag image_path(@photo) %>
```

And route:

```
match "/image", to: 'images#image', via: 'get'
```

And inside my controller I have the following method:

```
def image
    @image = Image.where("id = ?", params[:id]).first
    send_file @image.image.url.to_s, :disposition => 'inline', :type => 'image/jpeg', :x_sendfile => true
end
```

The problem is when method `image` is triggered, image is not displayed and I receive the following error in console:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass)
```

What do you think could be a problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the meaning of the error:**
the image is belong to @image's class.Your @image is nil,so the there is no so called nil.image.

**solution**
change you action route to "match "/image/:id", to: 'images#image', via: 'get'"
so the link will be [http://sitename/images/image/9],9 is the params[:id].

in your controller,you should replace the 9 to your variable(like "#{object.id}").

hope for help,sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Your route isn't set up correctly.  It isn't passing an id paramater to the image action so your "params[:id]" is returning nil, thereby your @image variable ends up nil.

Try this in your routes file:

```
match "image/:id", to: 'images#image', via: 'get'
```

While you're at it, you might as well use the shorter version being that your using Rails 4(according to your tags, anyway):

```
get "image/:id", to: 'images#image'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `@image` value, it seems that Photo has no record with the given id.